# Outbound calls with Twilio Rest Api are not executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twilio, restsharp

I'm building an application and one of the features is integrated with Twilio.

I have all the IVR flow done with Asp.Net Mvc 3 and everything is working correctly so far. 
However, one of the features is to have the user input a phone number and have Twilio call that number and play something once the other user answers.

I'm using the Twilio REST API to make the call, but the call is not being done and I don't have any error on the application or on Twilio.

What I'm doing is this: I have an Action that receive the data from twilio

```
public ActionResult Dial(Call request, int opt)
{

    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(Configuration.TwilioAccKey, Configuration.TwilioAuthKey);
    twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(Configuration.TwilioPhoneNumber, 
                                "+" + request.Digits,
                                string.Format("{0}/Calls/Endorsement/Play?opt={1}", Configuration.BaseUrl, opt));

    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    response.Redirect("/Calls/Endorsement/Play?opt=" + opt, "GET");
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

The response after the REST call is being executed and the outbound call doesn't throw any error.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code to initiate the outbound call looks correct.

Its possible that an exception is being returned from the REST API.  I've changed your code to use the InitiateOutboundCall methods callback parameter to check if the RestException property is not null:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(Configuration.TwilioAccKey,
                                  Configuration.TwilioAuthKey);
twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(Configuration.TwilioPhoneNumber,
                        "+" + request.Digits,
                        string.Format("{0}/Calls/Endorsement/Play?opt={1}", Configuration.BaseUrl, opt),
                        call =>
                        {
                            if (call.RestException != null)
                            {
                                //handle the rest error
                            }
                        }
                    );
```

If RestException is null and nothing is being logged in the Twilio debugger log, then your best option might be to break out Fiddler and see whats happening during the actual request to the API.

Comment: I fixed it, turns out, the rest API does a POST and my actions where all GET so I change that and used the CallOptions object as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and want to post here in case someone else finds this issue like I did.  (At the time this is the only thing that shows up in a search for "InitiateOutboundCall".)

In my case no exceptions were thrown either by my app or by Twilio.  The call to InitiateOutboundCall simply was not doing anything.

The docs make it clear that the URL must be absolute and I had left off the "http://".  After adding this everything worked as expected.